# detect notification text in protractor

Tags: notifications, protractor

I have a notification which pop ups on success or failure of some action and fades out after 2-3 seconds. I need to verify text of notification but can not find any way. Please help.
All other solutions found on stackoverflow and on other platforms didnt work for me.

[HTML of notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvhA2.png)

Comment: can you provide the html of the popup?

Comment: updated, attached HTML

Comment: Protractor waits for Angular to be stable. If you have any animation running, this might be hard to test.

Comment: I would need more information to provide a proper answer but I would suggest disabling browser synchronization before the notification text verification and then re-enabling it after.   browser.ignoreSynchronization=true; expect($('.notification-popup')).toBe('YOUR TEXT'); browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;

Comment: let me give it a try. can you please elaborate what information you need ? i can provide more details if needed